# Get date when you add new element to class

Tags: python

I am noob to python and was curious,

> I work with classes in Python and every element of the class has different values based of the date. And the date is always the same date as I add this element to the class.

Is there a way to automatically save the current date in the class?

> For example: Today is 20.07.2020 and I am adding a new element today.
>
> ```
> new_element = some_class(x1, x2)
> ```

And then the next day for example, I want to take a look at this element. And do this:

`new_element.date` would give me the date of the previous day (since I added it this day).

Comment: What happens when your application is restarted? All fields lose their updated date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime module. It might look like this.

```
from datetime import date

class some_class:
    def __init__(self, x1, x2):
        self.date = date.today()
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're question is a little confusingly worded (maybe it would help if you provided some concrete examples), but here's how I understand it: You have a class that has behavior based on date, and you'd like to have objects that stay consistent between sessions.

This is called **persistence**, and by default, all data from a program is lost when it stops running. To have persistent data, you have to save it to disk somehow. There is a few ways to go about this:

First, you could identify what data describes the object (like the date for example), then save it to a file as text. Then you construct the objects based on the data from the saved file.

Second, there is actually a very simple way to create persistent objects in python, and that is with the `pickle` module, which allows you to save and load whole python objects.